# Find the solutions of $y\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=0$.

Tags: calculus, analysis, partial-differential-equations

For all continuous functions $\varphi$,   $F(x,y)=\varphi(x^2+y^2)$ satisfies the partial differential equation
$$y\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=0.$$
I know little about PDE. But I wonder whether there exist other solutions or not.

Answer (score 0):

$$y\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial x}-x\frac{\partial F(x,y)}{\partial y}=0.$$

Use the method of characteristics:

$$\dfrac{dx}{y}=\dfrac{dy}{-x}=\dfrac{dF}{0}$$

From $dx/y=-dy/x \implies x^2+y^2=c_1$ and $dx/y=dF/0 \implies F = c_2=\varphi(c_1)=\varphi(x^2+y^2)$.

Answer (score 0):

Let an $r>0$ be given and consider the auxiliary function
$$f(t):=F(r\cos t,r\sin t)\ .$$
Then
$$\eqalign{f'(t)&=F_x(r\cos t,r\sin t)(-r\sin t)+F_y(r\cos t,r\sin t)(r\cos t)\cr &=-y F_x(x,y)+xF_y(x,y)\cr &\equiv0\ ,\cr}$$
whereby $x:=r\cos t$, $y:=r\sin t$. It follows that $F$ is constant on concentric circles, hence can be written in the form
$$F(x,y)=g\bigl(\sqrt{x^2+y^2}\bigr)$$
with a function $g:\>{\mathbb R}_{>0}\to{\mathbb R}$ of one variable.

Answer (score 0):

Rephrasing of Christian's answer- the PDE can be written $\mathbf x^⟂ \cdot \nabla F = 0$, where $\mathbf x^⟂ := (y,-x)$ is a vector perpendicular to $\mathbf x=(x,y)$. This means that the level sets of $F$ are perpendicular to $\mathbf x$ at every point $\mathbf x$, and one readily checks this property for circles centred around the origin.